# What does this symbol that looks like $\Lambda^3_3$ mean in this expression involving combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, notation, combinations

I found this symbol in the answer of a math question:

A={1, 2, 3, 4, 5} B={6, 7, 8}

### How many mappings (from set A to B) there are that make every element in set B has inverse image（s).

The solution of this question is written in the picture below:

[image]

However, it doesn't clearly explain the solving steps and the lambda symbol circled in the picture.

Comment: Could you add more context to the equation. It might help users figure out its use.

Comment: It's a capital lambda.  I think you'll have to give some more context before someone can tells you what it means in this case.  Instead of posting a screen shot use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the equation in which the symbol appears, and explain where it comes from.

Comment: No, it is a rather poor question, because it does not include context .

Comment: Where did you find this formula? Can you show the surrounding prose? $\Lambda$ can mean a number of things depending on the context.

Comment: I just added the context, but it might not be very clear in meaning for it is translated from another language.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $\lambda$ is used to represent the eigenvalues of a matrix in linear algebra, although I'm not sure how it is used in this context.

Comment: Based on the bulge on right side, that looks like an $A$, not a $\Lambda$. Either way, the context now provided makes its meaning clear. I'm writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count how many mappings ("[functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29)") from $A$ to $B$ that "make (the [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_%28mathematics%29) of) every element in set $B$ have a nonempty inverse image" (i.e., that are [onto/surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function)), we can count in the following way:

The set $A$ will be partitioned into exactly three subsets by which elements of $B$ they map to. Case I: At most two elements of $A$ map to the same element of $B$, so that the sizes of the subsets are $2,2,1$. Case II: Three elements of $A$ all map to the same element of $B$, so that the sizes of the subsets are $1,1,3$.

In each case, we can count the functions by multiplying [the number of ways to partition $A$ into three subsets of that shape] by [the number of ways to assign the subsets to the three elements of $B$]. Then we add the answers together at the end.

For Case I, we can choose two out of the five elements of $A$ to be in the first subset, choose two of the remaining three to be in the second subset (and then the remaining element makes up the last subset), and then divide by $2$ since the order of which is the "first" subset of size $2$ doesn't matter for the partition. Using [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), this gives us $\dfrac{{5\choose2}{ 3\choose2}}{2}$ for the "ways to partition" in Case I. It seems this source writes combinations like $5\choose2$ as "$C_5^2$", etc. I've seen the opposite convention ($C^5_2$) more commonly, but Wikipedia says that $C_5^2$ is common in, for instance, the Russian mathematics tradition.

Similarly, for Case II, we can choose one element of the five to make up the first subset, one of the remaining four to make up the second (so that the remaining three form the last subset), and divide by $2$ since the order of the two singletons doesn't matter.

Finally, for either case, we need to count the ways to select all three subsets out to map to $6$, $7$, and $8$ where order now matters. Using [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), this number is sometimes written ${}_3P{}_3$ or $P^3_3$ in English texts.

This gives us a final answer of $\dfrac{{5\choose2}{ 3\choose2}}{2}P^3_3+\dfrac{{5\choose1}{ 4\choose1}}{2}P^3_3=\dfrac{\frac{5*4}2\frac{3*2}2}{2}*6+\dfrac{5*4}{2}*6=150$.

The I wonder if the source of the image is written in the Kazakh language (or a related language) where the word for permutation seems to be "Алмастыру", so that the symbol is not a Greek "Λ", but a Cyrillic "А".

Comment: +1. A beautiful analysis, against the imagination of people, wanted to close this question.

Comment: This is very clear and helpful thanks a lot